# Python .exe file doesn't open

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I did this project with 'pyautogui' and then I created an executable file (.exe) with 'pyinstaller', but when I open the .exe file the window opens and then closes and nothing happens. If anyone could help me ...

```
from pyautogui import *
from time import sleep


def sclick(x, y):
    moveTo(x, y)
    sleep(0.8)
    click()
    sleep(0.5)


def dclick(x, y):
    doubleClick(x, y)
    sleep(0.8)


def w(text):
    typewrite(text)


def getp(secs):
    sleep(secs)
    print(position())


hotkey('win', 'd')
dclick(33, 519)
sleep(15)
sclick(181, 43)
w('Hello')
sleep(5)
press('enter')
w("What's up?")
```

Comment: Did you add --onefile to the cmd command?

Comment: Most likely it opened and closed because the program executed and closed.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code and built the with pyinstaller --onfile mytest.py and everything seems working fine

Comment: @MarkCostello I didn't do it, I'll try. thanks for the tip

Comment: first run it manually in console/terminal/cmd.exe - probably it displays some error and close program. Usually problem is that PyInstaller can't add some module/library and you have to manually add it to configuration when you run PyInstaller.

Comment: Thanks @MarkCostello , I managed to solve the problem with --onefile

Comment: Glad to hear, mate

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. Your code executes and then closes right away when I run it. The simplest way to keep the terminal open is by add `raw_input()` or `input()` for `python3` to the end of the code. You will have to press enter for the code to stop running afterword.

Comment: @mateus, did this fix your problem?

Comment: I even tried to do that, but it keeps closing. Thank you anyway. Sorry for any mistake in English, I'm Brazilian :)